# How to write a regex expression to match strings which is concat by "00" and "11"?

Tags: regex

that is to say, the string is combined with pair "00" and "11"s.

Example:
match: "0000"  "0011"  "111111"  "110011"
not match: "000" "0100" "00111" "120011" "1000"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see solution below:

https://regex101.com/r/59Q9yC/1

```
^(00|11)+$
```